# Find the total in a receipt got by OCR - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, ocr

I have problems in finding the total paid by the user within the string of the receipt, obtained through API vision.

For example:

```
$testo2 = "Del burger Sr Via Carlo del Prete 106/d 50127 FIRENZE C.F. E P.IVA 08380120482 BRUNCH MAMMAMIA ONION RINGS SPICCHI PATATE ACQUA 0.5L TAVOLO 88 EURO 6,50 6,50 4,00 3,00 1,00 TOTALE EURO CONTANTI 21,00 21,00 NR.0057 23/05/18 20:21 MF U1 72005985";
```

To find the total I tried to search within a for the dot or comma (some receipts have the dot and the other comma), then check if there are two numbers after the dot or a comma and then a while that search numbers before the comma until it finds the character found is a number. Then I put the values into an array and invert it in such a way to compose a complete price string (including the values after the comma). Prices are then entered into an array.

```
 for($i = 1; $i <= $lenghtTesto2 - 1; $i++)
{
   if($testo2[$i] == "." || $testo2[$i] == ",")
   {
      if($testo2[$i + 1] == "0" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "1" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "2" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "3" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "4" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "5" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "6" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "7" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "8" || $testo2[$i + 1] == "9")
      {
         if($testo2[$i + 2] == "0" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "1" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "2" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "3" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "4" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "5" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "6" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "7" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "8" || $testo2[$i + 2] == "9")
         { 

          $check = true;
          while($check)
          {
              if($testo2[$i - $j] == "0" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "1" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "2" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "3" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "4" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "5" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "6" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "7" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "8" || $testo2[$i - $j] == "9")
              {          


                array_push($arrPrezzi_invertiti, $testo2[$i - $j]);

                $j++;

              }
              else
              {
                 $prezzo = "";
                 $totaleFinale = "";
                 $dopoPunto1 = $testo2[$i + 1];
                 $dopoPunto2 = $testo2[$i + 2];
                 $j = 1;
                 $lenght_arrPrezzi_invertiti = count($arrPrezzi_invertiti);


                 for($k = $lenght_arrPrezzi_invertiti - 1; $k >= 0; $k--)
                 {
                     $totaleFinale .= $arrPrezzi_invertiti[$k];

                 }

                 $prezzo = $totaleFinale . "." . $dopoPunto1 . $dopoPunto2;

                 array_push($array, $prezzo);

                 $check = false;
              }   
          }              
     }
  }
}
}
```

Money are 6,50 6,50 4,00 3,00 1,00 21,00 21,00

[image: First example of receipt]

[image: Second example of receipt]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, what's the problem? You didn't specified. Second, have you tried using REGEX? It's cleaner. And please specify exactly where are the money listed in the string. Not all of us understand Italian

Comment: Are you trying to create a generic solution or will the string always be in this exact format?

Comment: Isn't it simply the first number after the word `TOTALE` (assuming `CONTANTE` means cash, and could also be a different word (or words), so you may want to be flexible about that? So I think you want to isolate everything from the first digit after TOTALE up until the first space after that.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson the string always be in this exact format

Comment: @GolezTrol I wouldn't know how to achieve that

Comment: _"the string always be in this exact format"_ - Didn't you say: _"some receipts have the dot and the other comma"_? That's not what I call "exact format". So what else can differ? Are you 100% sure that it will always say `TOTALE EURO CONTANTI` before the total or can that change as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes it will always say `TOTALE EURO CONTANTI`

Comment: Let me ask you this.  Is the total always the 2nd to last dollar amount from the end of the receipt.

Comment: on the second receipt, is that all of the data or did you just cut it off, please post code with your real strings and not pictures, I need to test using your real strings.

Comment: The second one has a different format, and doesn't have this text which you said would always be there.

Comment: You keep changing the specs. You say one thing, then you show us the opposite. When you post a question, these things needs to be _clear_ or you're basically just wasting everyones time. It's actually pretty disrespectful for the people that takes time to try and help you. This is a rabbit hole I'm gonna avoid. I'm out...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for being unclear.

Comment: @Joseph_J the images I posted are the real strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_match();

You will have to add possible word combinations to `[\sEURO|\sCONTANTI|\sECT.]`

Anyways this will give you an idea.  Tinker with it till you get it working how you want.

```
$testo2 = "Del burger Sr Via Carlo del Prete 106/d 50127 FIRENZE C.F. E P.IVA 08380120482 BRUNCH MAMMAMIA ONION RINGS SPICCHI PATATE ACQUA 0.5L TAVOLO 88 EURO 6,50 6,50 4,00 3,00 1,00 TOTALE EURO CONTANTI 21,00 21,00 NR.0057 23/05/18 20:21 MF U1 72005985";
$testo2 = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $testo2);
preg_match('/[\s\S]{0,}TOTALE\s[\sEURO|\sCONTANTI]{0,}\s(.*?)\s/', $testo2, $match);

echo $match[1];  //<--- Outputs "21,00"
```

***Second Solution***

I'm sure you could go regex crazy and get something to work, but we would need multiple examples to draw from. A better idea may be to make an assumption that the total will always be the highest amount on the receipt.  If that is the case we can do something like this:

```
function getReceiptTotal($receipt){

  preg_match_all('/\d+[\.,]\d+\s/', $receipt, $match);

  $comma = preg_match('/,/', $match[0][0]) ? TRUE : FALSE;

  for($i = 0; $i < count($match[0]); $i++){

    $match[0][$i] = trim($match[0][$i]);

    if($comma){

      $temp[] = preg_replace('/,/', '.', $match[0][$i]);

    } 

  }

  sort($temp);

  $total = end($temp);

  if($comma){

    return preg_replace('/\./', ',', $total);


  } else {

    return $total;

    }

}

echo getReceiptTotal($testo2); //Will output "21,00".
```

This should work for all your receipt types.

Comment: $testo2 is an example of receipt, but user with OCR can get  the text from different receipts. Is this solution going to be generic or specific?

Comment: You need to tell us that!  We are trying to find patterns to match from.  This will work for any receipt data where the price falls after the word totale & the words (EURO or CONTANTI).

Comment: @AlessioRaddi - Make your mind up. Will the string always be in the exact same format (same text) or can it differ? You state different things. First you say _"some receipts have the dot and the other comma"_, then you say that it will be in this exact format. This will solve your issue, the exact format and handles both dots and commas. If other things can differ, _you need to tell us_ or you're wasting both yours and our time.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the recipt can contain dots or commas. I've just checked that `TOTALE EURO CONTANTI` can differ and their values might be moved after and before them

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added the examples of two different receipts in my question

Comment: @Joseph_J Tried it out and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To find the total you might use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

[`TOTALE EURO CONTANTI\s*\K\d+[.,]\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/48c1rT/2)

Or with one or more whitespace characters between TOTALE EURO CONTANTI:

[`TOTALE\s+EURO\s+CONTANTI\s+\K\d+[.,]\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/pAy4xG/1)

You could match `TOTALE EURO CONTANTI` followed by zero or more whitespace characters, `\s*` and then reset the starting point of the match. Then match one or more digits, a comma or a dot using a character class followed by one or more digits `\d+[.,]\d+`

```
$re = '/TOTALE EURO CONTANTI\s*\K\d+,\d+/';
$str = 'Del burger Sr Via Carlo del Prete 106/d 50127 FIRENZE C.F. E P.IVA 08380120482 BRUNCH MAMMAMIA ONION RINGS SPICCHI PATATE ACQUA 0.5L TAVOLO 88 EURO 6,50 6,50 4,00 3,00 1,00 TOTALE EURO CONTANTI 21,00 21,00 NR.0057 23/05/18 20:21 MF U1 72005985';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // 21,00
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/KZBIK)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for your comment. I have updated my answer with a character class which would match either a dot or a comma.

Comment: I added the examples of two different receipts in my question